# Using Py2app with a GUI from QT Creator

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, py2app

I created a GUI in QT Creatro and stored this as a *.ui file. 
Using PyQT I made a GUI that works fine when it is launched as

```
$ python pyapp.py
```

In order to build this app into something that can be executed by double clicking on it, I used Py2app. However, upon clicking the icon twice, I get the following error in the dialog that appears:

```
pygui Error
```

After opening the console, it seems that the following gives rise to this error:

```
12/06/2015 15:58:30.084 pygui[29757]: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mainwindow.ui'
```

It seems that the gui that I created with QT Creator is not found by the app when it opens. Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because py2app would not be able to find files specified through string paths in the code. It will not include those files in the binary. You can do one of two things to solve your problem.

1) You have to convert your .ui file to .py file using `pyuic4` (included in PyQt4 installation). After this step you will have a .py file. Then instead of using .ui, import .py file and inherit your class from the *class generated in .py file*. This will allow py2app to include the ui from a python module instead of searching for .ui file.

2) You can simply manually place the .ui file in the same directory where the py2app created the binary. It should work without errors.

**UPDATE**

If you want to try 2nd solution, you need to specify the complete path to the .ui file. You can do this by using `__file__` attribute in the python module. Instead of `uic.loadUiType("mainwindow.ui")`, use `uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "mainwindow.ui"))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the second option first, but that didn't work. In my code I load the GUI using uic.loadUiType("mainwindow.ui")[0] . Is this the correct way of doing it, or should I somehow first try to find out the path from where the app is launched? I am still looking in to the first option

Comment: I am updating my answer for the 2nd solution of my answer.